# Why can't I change a class variable of a class derived from QWidget?

Tags: python, pyside2, class-variables

Why does this code...

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget


class A:
    attribute = None


class Q(QWidget):
    attribute = None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(A.attribute)
    A.attribute = 42
    print(A.attribute)

    print(Q.attribute)
    Q.attribute = 42
    print(Q.attribute)
```

...yield this output...

```
None
42
None
None
```

...instead of this output?

```
None
42
None
42
```

And what changes would be necessary to get the second output?

I tested this on:

- PySide2: 5.9.0~a1
- Python: 3.7.3
- OS: Windows and Linux

Comment: With PySide2 5.14.2 and python 3.8.2 on Linux I don't see the problem, try updating the version of pyside2 in addition to pointing out your environment: pyside2 version, python version and OS.

Comment: Perhaps you need to use setAttribute(), found in the docs https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QWidget.html#

Comment: I think it is a bug from an old version of pyside2

Comment: @Sri Qt Attributes have nothing to do with class variables.

Comment: @eyllanesc Seems you're right. I updated Python and PySide2 as well and now it works. Weird. Thank you very much!